# How to use Java Generics to enforce type restrictions

Tags: java, algorithm, generics, design-patterns

This question is a bit advanced so naturally also a little complicated. I will try and do my best to be as clear as possible.

As the title reads, I'd like to use Java Generics to enforce type restrictions when constructing an objects from some top level (main).

I have never really used Java generics but I found a pretty good use case for it which I am not sure how to implement.

I'd like to enforce type restriction when composing an object. Let me try to clarify with an example:

I have a top level main method here where I am evoking a NumberEngine object where I initialize and call methods of it. Notice when I call setExecuteBehavior(), I pass it an object of type RunNumberEvaluation (which along with RunStringEvaluation implements an interface called ExecutionBehavior).

As the name implies, NumberEngine works only with Numbers and not Strings, so it's inappropriate for me to pass setExecuteBehavior() an object of type RunStringEvaluation. How can I enforce this behavior at compile time?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    NumberEngine numberEngine = new NumberEngine();
    numberEngine.init("/path/to/forms");
    numberEngine.getEngineVesion();

    numberEngine.setExecuteBehavior(new RunNumberEvaluation);
    numberEngine.performExecution();


    // Here this should not compile, essentially throw me a compile error saying it can only accept 
    // an object of type RunNumberEvaluation, sincle NumberEngine can only run 
    // objects of type RunNumberEvaluation, etc...
    numberEngine.setExecuteBehavior(new RunStringEvaluation());
    numberEngine.performExecution();

}
```

So here I would like to basically make NumberEngine's setExecuteBehavior to only accept behavior which is relevent to it like the processing of data which pertains to numbers and not Strings. And vice-versa for StringEngine. I want StringEngine to only accept objects which pertains to Strings and not Numbers.

> How can I accomplish this with Java generics?

I was thinking about something like this...

```
NumberEngine<? extends Numbers> extends Engine
```

Not even sure if this makes sense...

I have included working code below as an illustration of what I'm attempting to communicate.

I have an object of type Engine which is an abstract class with many extending concrete classes such as StringEngine, NumberEngine, et cetera. I have decoupled  the algorithmic functionality into an interface with classes that implement that interface.

**Base Abstract Class**

```
public abstract class Engine {
    ExecuteBehavior executeBehavior;

    public void setExecuteBehavior(ExecuteBehavior executeBehavior) {
        this.executeBehavior = executeBehavior;
    }
    public void performExecution() {
        executeBehavior.execute();
    }
    public abstract void init(String pathToResources);
}
```

**Concrete Implementing Class 1**

```
public class StringEngine extends Engine {
    public StringEngine() {
        executeBehavior = new RunNumberEvaluation();
    }

    @Override
    public void init(String pathToResources) {
        System.out.println("Initializing StringEngine with resources "+pathToResources);
        System.out.println("Successfully initialized StringEngine!");
    }
}
```

**Concrete Implementing Class 2**

```
public class NumberEngine extends Engine {
    public NumberEngine() {
        executeBehavior = new RunStringEvaluation();
    }

    @Override
    public void init(String pathToResources) {
        System.out.println("Initializing NumberEngine with resources "+pathToResources);
        System.out.println("Successfully initialized NumberEngine!");
    }
}
```

**Algorithm Interface**

```
public interface ExecuteBehavior {
    void execute();
}
```

**Algorithm Implementation 1**

```
public class RunNumberEvaluation implements ExecuteBehavior {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // some processing
        System.out.println("Running numeric evaluation");
    }
}
```

**Algorithm Implementation 2**

```
public class RunStringEvaluation implements ExecuteBehavior {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // some processing
        System.out.println("Running string evaluation");
    }
}
```

If you haven't noticed but here I'm making use of the strategy pattern where I segregate the varying algorithms into a family via interface from the static non-changing code.

Edit: I'd like to maintain the strategy pattern used here.

Comment: Interesting suggestion but if I moved `setExecuteBehavior()` from Engine to it's subclasses, it would break inheritance and the Strategy pattern I am employing

Comment: New to object orientation?  Inheritance is maintained if you made `setExecuteBehavior()` abstract.  You would do this if the method is part of your API and you wouldn't if it is not.

Comment: I should have said code reuse but more importantly would this break the Strategy pattern?

Comment: that's a wrong question to ask. you don't match your problem to patterns. you match patterns to your problem.

Comment: Well said, theoretically that is true but I worry of downstream implications if such a fundamental pattern is broken. It may introduce regressions. Maintaining this pattern is very important. I will edit my question to include this criteria

Answer (score 1):

First put the "variable" classes into Engine's formal parmaeter list:

```
public abstract class Engine<B extends ExecuteBehavior> {
    B executeBehavior;

    public void setExecuteBehavior(B executeBehavior) {
        this.executeBehavior = executeBehavior;
    }
    public void performExecution() {
        executeBehavior.execute();
    }
    public abstract void init(String pathToResources);
}
```

Then you can define the subclasses the way you want:

```
public class StringEngine extends Engine<RunStringEvaluation> {
    public StringEngine() {
        executeBehavior = new RunStringEvaluation();
    }

    @Override
    public void init(String pathToResources) {
        System.out.println("Initializing StringEngine with resources "+pathToResources);
        System.out.println("Successfully initialized StringEngine!");
    }
}
```

In the example code you've provided, you don't need that. Just move `setExecuteBehavior` to the subclasses and make it private.

Comment: exposing setter makes perfect sense as the user might set engine anytime they want, as long as they are setting the right behavior. i think your first code piece does the job OP wants already.

Comment: Yes. My comment is that in the example code, the generics solution isn't needed. I don't mean to imply that in _other_ code, the no-setter solution is suitable.

Comment: @PaulHicks your solution looks like exactly what I was looking for. However I do have a followup question. Would it be possible to have have mulitple extensions, like say in the future I wanted to extend functionality and add more engine specific functionality for `StringEngine` such as `RunStringFormatting` how would the syntax look like? 

 `public abstract class Engine<B extends ExecuteBehavior>` and then `public class StringEngine extends Engine<RunStringEvaluation, RunStringFormatting>` ?

Comment: You could do that. Or you could go @Hamady C.'s way and make the Formatter and Evaluator classes both be parameterized and pass that parameter from the Engine subclass. I suggest not worrying about it until you need it. By then you will have more experience with generics and you will have an idea which solution will work best for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple to achieve that using generics, you were totally right trying to use generics for that

All you had to do is to change your classes like this

First the interface

```
public interface ExecuteBehavior<T> {
    void execute();
}
```

Then the abstract implementation

```
public abstract class Engine<T> {
    ExecuteBehavior<T> executeBehavior;

    public void setExecuteBehavior(ExecuteBehavior<T> executeBehavior) {
        this.executeBehavior = executeBehavior;
    }
    public void performExecution() {
        executeBehavior.execute();
    }
    public abstract void init(String pathToResources);
}
```

And finally the RunNumberEngine and NumberEngine

```
public class RunNumberEvaluation implements ExecuteBehavior<Number> {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // some processing
        System.out.println("Running numeric evaluation");
    }
}
```

NumberEngine

```
public class NumberEngine extends Engine<Number> {
    public NumberEngine() {
        executeBehavior = new RunNumberEvaluation();
    }

    @Override
    public void init(String pathToResources) {
        System.out.println("Initializing NumberEngine with resources "+pathToResources);
        System.out.println("Successfully initialized NumberEngine!");
    }
}
```

And RunStringEngine, followed by StringEngine

```
public class RunStringEvaluation implements ExecuteBehavior<String> {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // some processing
        System.out.println("Running string evaluation");
    }
}
```

StringEngine

```
public class StringEngine extends Engine<String> {
    public StringEngine() {
        executeBehavior = new RunStringEvaluation();
    }

    @Override
    public void init(String pathToResources) {
        System.out.println("Initializing StringEngine with resources "+pathToResources);
        System.out.println("Successfully initialized StringEngine!");
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution actually is better.

Comment: When I was mentioning Number and String I was speaking with respect to the Implementing classes of ExecutionBehavior. But this look promising as well

Comment: Would it be possible to have generics to extend multiple types, like say in the future I wanted to extend functionality and add more engine specific functionality for StringEngine such as RunStringFormatting how would the syntax look like? public abstract class Engine<B extends ExecuteBehavior> and then public class StringEngine extends Engine<RunStringEvaluation, RunStringFormatting>?

Comment: The interface makes no use of the formal parameter and does not depend on it.  It would be simpler to define the interface without it.

Comment: @barthelonafan the nice thing about this definition is it only mentions `String`; it doesn't care if it's formatting or executing or others. so it doesn't impact your class signature at all. you will just need to add a method to it.